# How to convert a LiveCD into a vmlinuz and initrd to PXE Boot Load Slowly

Tags: pxe

I need to make a emergency PXE bootloader for a LIVECD (not the ubuntu netboot small cd, but rather a desktop livecd to boot from the command line). Will this work:

```
# Create a cpio archive of just the ISO and append it to the initrd image. 
( echo "ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso" | cpio -H newc --quiet -o ) |  gzip -9 |   cat ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso_EXTRACTED/casper/initrd0.img - > tftpboot/initrd0.img

# Kernel image.
cp ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso_EXTRACTED/isolinux/vmlinuz0 tftpboot/vmlinuz0

# pxelinux bootloader part:
LABEL pxeboot
    KERNEL vmlinuz0
    APPEND initrd=initrd0.img root=/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso             rootfstype=iso9660 rootflags=loop
ONERROR LOCALBOOT 0
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does anyone have any guidance on this? :(

Comment: anyone? Sorry for bumping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That configuration loads the whole image through a slow protocol like TFTP.

- Try other option using NFS protocol.

  ```
  apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

  mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
  mount -o loop ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/ubuntu-desktop-cd
  ```
- Share it through NFS

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/exports
  ```

  Add this line

  ```
  /mnt/ubuntu-desktop-cd 192.168.0.0/24(ro,insecure,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check)
  ```
- Start NFS service

  ```
  service nfs-kernel-server restart
  ```
- In `APPEND` line, replace `root`, `rootfstype` and `rootfstype` with:

  ```
  netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.10:/mnt/ubuntu-desktop-cd
  ```

**Note**: I used these IP's just as an example.

192.168.0.10 is IP of the NFS server

192.168.0.0/24 Is local network range.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet#A_variation:_Booting_the_.22Live_CD.22_image

Comment: I've tried this to boot the avlinux livecd over PXE. The initial boot works, but then it dies with an kernel exception.
I suspect the livecd must have some explicit support for this, or it would not work.

Comment: @markus_b, have you tried booting avlinux with a ubuntu kernel?